# Toggle widget visibility with single button

Tags: google-apps-script

The following code should write the inverse of true/false as found in the textbox back into the textbox when the button is clicked - but it doesn't work correctly. It will work correctly one way, but not the other (the one that works is whichever ClickHandler was defined last). I've tried using validateNotMatches too but no joy.

If I change the code so that the label's text is updated instead of the textbox's then that works fine.

I am aware of suggested workarounds such as using two buttons, but *I just want to know if I'm doing something wrong or if this looks like a bug in GAS*. Thanks.

```
function doGet(e)
{
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();

  var tb = app.createTextBox().setText('true');
  var button = app.createButton('button');
  var label = app.createLabel().setText('-');

  button.addClickHandler(app.createClientHandler()
                  .validateMatches(tb, 'true')
                  //.forTargets(label).setText('false')
                  .forTargets(tb).setText('false')
                 );
  button.addClickHandler(app.createClientHandler()
                  .validateMatches(tb, 'false')
                  //.forTargets(label).setText('true')
                  .forTargets(tb).setText('true')
                 );

  return app.add(app.createHorizontalPanel().add(tb).add(button).add(label));
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. I've raised [issue 2226](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2226).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a bug... both events fire. The validation happens on the current state of the widget, not on the state when the event was fired, so after you flip it to "false" the second handler validates and flips it back to "true".

Comment: makes sense once explained, but I think users of this API, developers, will always expect that it's the state when fired. It would make our lives easier if this could be changed. Maybe consider the issue opened a request to change this behavior.

Comment: I don't think we can change this anymore. It would be likely to subtly change a lot of existing apps subtly, possibly breaking them. The answer that we are going to give is that UiApp does not support this sort of toggleable event handling via ClientHandlers, and there are 3 suggested workarounds - ServerHandlers (which are slightly slower but totally support this), 2 widgets (annoying perhaps but simple, and works on the client) or full-featured HtmlService. UiApp is for simpler apps, and if you are pushing UiApp too far, at some point you are going to run into these limitations.

Comment: That logic does make sense, but I don't believe that's the whole story, it is more subtle than that. Let me demonstrate. Modify my code example by removing the second ClickHandler, and uncomment the line that sets the label text (so we're now setting the text for both the Label and the TextBox). Now here I would expect both forTargets to run but they don't. The Label's text isn't updated and the TextBox's is. Can you please explain that behaviour?

Comment: It's the same essential problem. Look at this slightly modified example:

  button.addClickHandler(app.createClientHandler()
                  .validateMatches(tb, 'true|foo')
                  .forTargets(tb).setText('foo')
                  .forTargets(label).setText('false')
                 );

Basically each forTargets is independently validated and the ordering is undefined. Ergo, if you change the validated object midstream, the resultd are undefined.

Comment: Thanks. It would be a great help if this sort of behaviour was mentioned in the documentation.